# Laravel How to Validate Integrity of Model ID when Saved

Tags: laravel, forms, validation

This might be a bit paranoid, but I'm wondering what other people do to ensure that ID of a model isn't spoofed when editing it from the front end. For instance, check out the following basic form:

```
<form id="form1" action="/profile/patch">
  @csrf
  <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{ $profile.id }}">
  <input type="text" name="name" value="{{ $profile.name }}" placeholder="Your Name">
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

A savvy but malicious person with permissions to manage multiple records could simply go into their Web Developer console and change the value of the ID hidden input. This example is a bit basic, but it could be used in more nefarious ways I'm thinking.

I thought about adding a second layer of validation by including the ID in the action URL:

```
<form id="form1" action="/profile/{{ $profile.id }}/patch">
  ...
```

... but this is just as easily spoofed.

Then there is javascript. Even something like this can be overwritten with a console command:

```
<script>
document.forms.form1.onsubmit = function() {
  // do some validation here
  document.forms.form1.elements['id'].value = {{ $profile.id }}; // dynamically insert the id
  return true;
}
</script>
```

It seems like session variables might be the only way to do it, but that could get messy real quick. Am I just going to have to live with this, or is there something I'm missing? Am I just being too paranoid?

Comment: you cant trust data in any requests, you have to validate and deal with authorization ... if they have permission to multiple things then they have permission to those things, so what is there to worry about

Comment: I get where you are coming from, and you are right, I'm probably overthinking this if they already have permissions, but the only validation you can do on an ID is that it exists or that the user has permissions to edit that particular record, not if it was the same ID you started with. I like KFoobar's idea to encrypt the ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either encrypt the IDs in the html form to prevent users from modifying it or even better: don't print the IDs (or other sensitive data) in the html form at all and use Form Request and Validation (in Laravel) to apply IDs and other data that don't need to be submitted with the form. [See documentation for Form Request here](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/validation#form-request-validation)

Example:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'user_id' => 'required|bail',
        'name' => 'required|string|bail',
    ];
}

protected function prepareForValidation()
{
    // This will add the user_id to the request after the form is submitted
    $this->merge([
        'user_id' => (auth()->check()) ? auth()->id() : null,
    ]);
}
```

If you need the IDs to be submitted with the form, you can use `prepareForValidation()` to decrypt the IDs instead:

```
protected function prepareForValidation()
{
    // This will decrypt the user id
    $this->merge([
        'user_id' => myDecryptFunction($this->input('hashed_user_id')),
    ]);
}
```

To collect the data in your controller, inject your Form Request like this:

```
public function store(MyFormRequest $request)
{
    $formDataAsArray = $request->validated();
}
```

Comment: I already use form requests and validation, I just don't understand how you can omit the ID when resubmitting the form from the front end? Your first example would work on a user editing their own profile, but not editing another user's profile for example.